# CKeditor : How to create a zoom plugin

Tags: ckeditor

CKeditor : How to create a zoom plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post explains the step by step to create such plugin: http://alfonsoml.blogspot.com/2010/01/zoom-plugin-for-ckeditor.html